# Sort data in graph in R

Tags: r

I have the following code :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x = cut)) +
  geom_bar()
```

with [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4TKi.jpg).

I would like to sort the graph on the count descending.

Comment: One way is to sort data before adding them to the graph. Kindly share your R code with sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of how to do it (it is probably possible just by using options within ggplot). But a way using `dplyr` library to first summarize the data and then use `ggplot` to plot the bar chart might look like this:

```
# load the ggplot library
library(ggplot2)
# load the dplyr library
library(dplyr)
# load the diamonds dataset
data(diamonds)

# using dplyr:
# take a dimonds dataset
newData <- diamonds %>%
        # group it by cut column
        group_by(cut) %>%
        # count number of observations of each type
        summarise(count = n())

# change levels of the cut variable
# you tell R to order the cut variable according to number of observations (i.e. count variable)
newData$cut <- factor(newData$cut, levels = newData$cut[order(newData$count, decreasing = TRUE)])

# plot the ggplot
ggplot(data = newData, aes(x = cut, y = count)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```